# Shared assembly versioning and issue tracking

Tags: version-control, mercurial, jira

We have 3 teams developing 3 different projects(.NET), and there is one project with common code and controls SharedLibrary. Each team references it using sub-repository in Mercurial.
Each team is allowed to push changes to SharedLibrary to fix bugs in their projects. So there is a possibility that fixing a bug in one project may introduce a bug in the second one.

We're using JIRA for issue tracking, and there are 4 projects (for each team and for SharedLibrary).

So, could anyone suggest a workflow, which reduces chances of integration failure(one team breaks other team project) and in case failure happened helps to reveal it as soon as possible?

Points to consider:

1. Do we need a version for SharedLibrary in JIRA? How it should be maintained?
2. Who and when verifies changes made to SharedLibrary?
3. What is the best way to organize branches in hg?
4. What is the best way to organize JIRA workflow? In what project in JIRA are the ShareLibrary issues filed?

Any help or examples of workflows/solutions for the similar situations are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

1. Yes, you should maintain versions for SharedLibrary just like you do your other projects. You should tie the release of each of your 3 projects to a specific version of SharedLibrary. If you just let any of the 3 project teams change it without referring to the other teams, you'll have a high risk of introducing non-compatible changes.
2. If SharedLibrary isn't maintained by a specific person or team, I'd suggest having a cross functional team made up of representatives from each project team that is responsible for reviewing updates to SharedLibrary.  They can use JIRA to track the issues by version. To verify that changes don't break other projects, have a comprehensive set of tests for each project that you can run in a continuous integration server such as Jenkins.
3. I don't have any particular suggestions here.
4. I would keep SharedLibrary as a separate JIRA project.